# Difficulties with save game file

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying this tutorial because I want to save some data in an XML file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx

But I get this error messages in the `SaveGameData` class:

```
IAsyncResult result = device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);
```

A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));
```

Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

What is wrong?

In addition, I don't know how to write something into the file. For example, I want to save the score into the save game file if the player presses Escape. How can I do that?

```
public struct SaveGameData
    {
        public string PlayerName;
        public Vector2 AvatarPosition;
        public int Level;
        public int Score;
    }
    // Open a storage container.
IAsyncResult result = device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(result);

// Close the wait handle.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

string filename = "savegame.sav";

// Check to see whether the save exists.
if (container.FileExists(filename))
   // Delete it so that we can create one fresh.
   container.DeleteFile(filename);

// Create the file.
Stream stream = container.CreateFile(filename);

// Convert the object to XML data and put it in the stream.
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));
  serializer.Serialize(stream, data);

// Close the file.
stream.Close();

// Dispose the container, to commit changes.
container.Dispose();

// Open a storage container.
IAsyncResult result =
    device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(result);

// Close the wait handle.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

string filename = "savegame.sav";

// Check to see whether the save exists.
if (!container.FileExists(filename))
{
   // If not, dispose of the container and return.
   container.Dispose();
   return;
}

// Open the file.
Stream stream = container.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));

SaveGameData data = (SaveGameData)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

// Close the file.
stream.Close();

// Dispose the container.
container.Dispose();
```

Comment: You should put your code inside a method

Comment: Should I put the entire code in a method? Or just a part of it?

Comment: Everything except the struct declaration. Then call that method whenever you need it